# Python <function functionName at 0x00000000>

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, input

I'm defining a function that I can call to store the user's input as a variable,
make sure it's a number, and convert the number to a integer for a formula later in the code.

So the idea is, when the program gets to **days** it prompts the user to input **getAnswer**, which launches the function, to check the answer the user gives, and convert it to an integer. Same thing with **worked**

```
def getAnswer(a):
    while True:
        if a.isdecimal():
            a = int()
            break
        print('Numbers only please...')

days = input(getAnswer)
worked = input(getAnswer)
```

This is what it ends up looking like <[function functionName at 0x013A1300](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVLqV.jpg)>

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you're trying to ask here; could you edit to clarify? Also, it appears that `getAnswer` doesn't actually return anything.

Comment: I tried to clean up the language the best I could for everyone, I'm still terribly new at Python.

Comment: *"follows my cursor at the input parts"*?!

Comment: Edit made, the picture is worth more than the words I was trying to put to it. =\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `input` by passing a function instead of a string prompting the user. Perhaps you mean:

```
days = getAnswer()
```

with `getAnswer()` defined to use `input` to get the response from the user, validate it, and then return it. For example,

```
def getAnswer():
    while True:
        a = input()
        try:
            return int(a)
        except ValueError:
            print('Numbers only please...')
```

In my opinion, this is rather clearer than passing the input function to `getAnswer()` and the `try...except` clause is a common and easily-understood Python idiom.

Comment: This fixed the issue, and I understand functions better, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`getAnswer` by itself, is a function. You are not calling it, for example, like this:

```
getAnswer(1)
```

I suspect what you tried to do is

```
days = getAnswer(input())
```

Note that the order of evaluation is from inside to outside. In other words, `input()` will be evaluated first, and then `getAnswer(...)`